# getText from a radiogroup, depending on which radio group is clicked

Tags: android, android-studio

I could get the Text if I disregard the other radio group, but i need 2 columns of radio group, therefore i created another one. Since then, i couldn't get the text from both radio groups. Here is the code:

```
Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            int selectedId = RadG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int selectedId1 = RadG1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId1);
            String Radbtn = rb.getText().toString().trim();
            String Radbtn1 = rb1.getText().toString().trim();
            String Vol = Vio.getText().toString();
            getUID = UID.getText().toString();
            String Contact = Cnumber.getText().toString();
            if (rb1.isChecked()) {
                String query = "Update Driver set ContactNumber='" + Contact + "', Violation='" + Radbtn + "',Comments='" + Vol + "' WHERE UID='" + getUID + "'";
                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (rb1.isChecked()) {
                String query = "Update Driver set ContactNumber='" + Contact + "', Violation='" + Radbtn1 + "',Comments='" + Vol + "' WHERE UID='" + getUID + "'";
                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the logcat:

```
04-12 22:19:43.904 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.RadioButton.getText()' on a null object reference
04-12 22:19:43.907 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err:     at com.orig3.thesis.Main2Activity$5.onClick(Main2Activity.java:251)
04-12 22:19:43.907 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
04-12 22:19:43.907 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
04-12 22:19:43.908 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
04-12 22:19:43.908 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
04-12 22:19:43.908 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
04-12 22:19:43.908 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7390)
04-12 22:19:43.908 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-12 22:19:43.908 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
04-12 22:19:43.908 25667-25667/com.orig3.thesis W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:926)
04-12 22:19:46.349 25667-25674/com.orig3.thesis I/zygote64: Debugger is no longer active
```

Here is the code for my radiogroup, and I am already using OnChangelistener, I cant seem to find why it still return null for my getCheckedRadioButtonId

```
RadG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId != -1 && isChecking) {
                    isChecking = false;
                    RadG1.clearCheck();
                }
                isChecking = true;
            }
        });

        RadG1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId != -1 && isChecking) {
                    isChecking = false;
                    RadG.clearCheck();
                }
                isChecking = true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a NullPointerException thrown on one of this two lines :

```
String Radbtn = rb.getText().toString().trim();
String Radbtn1 = rb1.getText().toString().trim();
```

It mean that one of your radio button is null, either `rb` or `rb1`. They are initialize by these lines :

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId1);
```

One being null means that `findViewById()` failed to find a view having `selectedId` as ID. One of your selected ID is not a valid value. You obtain them from these lines :

```
int selectedId = RadG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
int selectedId1 = RadG1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

If their nto valid it means getCheckRadioButtonId() returns something wrong. It means there is no radioButton selected in this group.

*(you could have found this diagnostic by yourself if you had debugged your code)*

**Solution**
*(Edited)*

You have to check if something is selected in each of your radioGroup because you could click on the save button when nothing in selected. Has explained is the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId()), if nothing is selected `getCheckedRadioButtonId` will return -1. So add a if `selectId!=-1` To make sure something is selected.

Comment: I am currently using OnCheckedChangeListener, I have edited my post above and added the codes for my radiogroups, i cant seem to find why it still returns null

Comment: @MarijonBaria I have edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: Thank you! I have used your explanation and edited my code :)